# Last date end of last month (last day of last month is not the end of the month)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table, something like the following (just adding the dates as I think the rest is not relevant for this question):

| Date |
| --- |
| 20/10/2023 |
| 10/10/2023 |
| 06/10/2023 |
| 01/10/2023 |
| 29/09/2023 |
| 16/09/2023 |
| 09/09/2023 |

As you can see the last day of the month is not the endo of the month.

I need to create a measure, something like the following:

```
myMeasure = 
    
VAR lDate = CALCULATE( LASTDATE('MyTable'[Date]), PREVIOUSMONTH(DateTable[Date]))

RETURN

CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Tickets'[ID]),
    DateTable[Date]=lDate
 )
```

The issue I am having with this is that it seems to display correctly when adding the Date from the DateTable and the measure to a table visual, but when adding the measure to a card it displays a (Blank) value.

What I want to do is each day to compare with the last available date of the previous month. So:

So if I select any of the folowing dates from my filter:
2

- 20/10/2023
- 10/10/2023
- 06/10/2023
- 01/10/2023

It would always return the value from the date:

- 29/09/2023

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Is your filter using your DateTable or the Dates from your fact/data table?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It is from my DateTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
myMeasure =
  var lDate = CALCULATE( LASTDATE('MyTable'[Date]), PREVIOUSMONTH(ENDOFMONTH(DateTable[Date])) )
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
     COUNT('Tickets'[ID]),
     FILTER(ALL('DateTable'[Date]), 'DateTable'[Date] = lDate)
    )
```

For it to work in a Card visual (or any visual), it needs a date context to know which prev month to look at. If you have a date slicer or date filter on the page, then it will work. If you don't then you can add a date filter to the card visual filter pane, you could use Relative date filtering with `is in this month`.

Comment: When I add this to a table visual with the date from my date table and the measure, it seems to work. but when trying to add it to a card visual it is blank.  I updated the question accordingly. Also the measure that I am using

Comment: Update the answer above.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thank you for your help. I did it with a different approach. I will mark your suggestion as resolved.